# On Noetherianity and local ness of a completed tensor product

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products, local-rings, completion, noetherian

Let $R$ be a  regular local complete (with respect to the maximal ideal) ring with field of fraction $K$. Let $S\cong R[[x_1,\cdots, x_n]]/J$ (this is a Noetherian local ring which is an $R$-algebra) for some ideal $J$.  Assume depth$(S)>0$.
Is the completed tensor product (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU)
$S \widehat{\otimes}_R K$ a Noetherian local ring containing  $K$ ?

Thoughts: Let $\mathfrak m$ be the unique maximal ideal of $S$. Since $K$ is a field, so the completed tensor product  $S \widehat{\otimes}_R K$  should just be the inverse limit of the system $\dfrac{S\otimes_R K}{\mathfrak m^n \otimes_R K}$. I have no idea how to analyze this.

Comment: $S \otimes_R K$ is a localization of $S$, right?  Hence $S \otimes_R K$ is Noetherian.  Now I think you are simply competing a Noetherian ring along some ideal. hence its Noetherian.  That said though, unless $R = K$, I think in your case you have that $m^n \otimes_R K = m^n \otimes_S (S \otimes_R K) = S \otimes_R K$.  Ie, you inverted elements of $R$ that are also in the ideal $m^n$.  So your completion is not very interesting unless I'm misreading things.

Comment: @KarlSchwede: sorry for the late reply, but I think you are right ... I'll think about it a bit more, and then probably close my question ...